# how do I check if a particular Layout is included in android from JAVA?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to do the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.product_details_editpage);
```

I want to check if product_details_editpage layout has another layout included in it?
If so, for the included layout components, I would like to reuse the handlers from elsewhere in the App.

If the included layout has a button such as Logout, then I dont want to re-implement that logout button handler again in th eactivity that sets calls setContentView() above.

What is the easiest way /best way to do this?

Comment: If I am wrong please correct me, you mention "reuse the handlers", here you mention event handlers? If so once setContentView runs, all the view will be recreated, so you have to re-assign them back to those view.

Comment: Doesn't inclusion of another layout happen statically? Then what is the use of performing a runtime check if you can figure out the included layouts even before compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agreed with above comments.
accept te discussion is closed.